# Unit testing Promise task in grails

Tags: unit-testing, grails, asynchronous

How do we unit test logic in Promises.task?

```
task{service.method()}
```

I want to validate invocation of the service method inside the task.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

I read in the documentation that in unit testing async processes, one can use this:

```
Promises.promiseFactory = new SynchronousPromiseFactory()
```

Tried adding it in my setup, but still does not work.

Answer (score 3):

## The long way

I've been struggling with this for a moment too.

I tried those:

1. [grails unit test + Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26345613/grails-unit-test-thread)
2. [Verify Spock mock with specified timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21666874/verify-spock-mock-with-specified-timeout)

Also tried the same solution from the docs as you:

```
Promises.promiseFactory = new SynchronousPromiseFactory()
```

All went with no luck.

## The solution

So I ended up with *meta classing*.

In the test's `setup` method, I mocked the `Promise.task` closure, so it runs the closure in the current thread, not in a new one:

```
def setup() {
    Promises.metaClass.static.task = { Closure c -> c() }
    // ...more stuff if needed...
}
```

Thanks to that, I can test the code as it wouldn't use *multi threading*.

Even I'm far from being 100% happy with this, I couldn't get anything better so far.

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of Grails (3.2.3 for instance), there is no need to mock, metaClass or use a Promise factory. I found out the promises in **unit** tests  get executed synchronously. Found no doc for that, I empirically added a sleep inside a promise and noticed the test waited for the pause to complete.

For integration tests and functional tests, that's another story: you have to change the promise provider, for instance in `BootStrap.groovy`:

```
if (Environment.current == Environment.TEST) {
    Promises.promiseFactory = new SynchronousPromiseFactory()
}
```

Like Marcin suggested, the `metaClass` option is not satisfactory. Also bear in mind that previous (or future) versions of Grails are likely to work differently.

Comment: Using `Promises.promiseFactory = new SynchronousPromiseFactory()` works great for me in my controller test. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are stuck with Grails 2 like dinosaurs such as me, then you can just copy the classes SynchronousPromiseFactory and SynchronousPromise from Grails 3 to your project and then the following works:
    Promises.promiseFactory = new Grails3SynchronousPromiseFactory()
(Class names are prefixed with Grails3 to make the hack more obvious)

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply mock/override the `Promises.task` method to invoke the provided closure directly.